# Objective-C: Use category method when the class is known at runtime

Tags: objective-c, class, runtime, categories

I'm using MagicalRecord and would like to be able to do something like

```
Car *newCar = [Car importFromObject:obj]; // where obj is a JSON object
```

but I would like to do it without prior knowledge of the class, having only the @"Car" string or Car as a Class object at runtime.

I know how to create a new car

```
id obj = [[NSClassFromString(@"Car") alloc] init];
```

but how should I call the importFromObject: method ?

Comment: If you have only two conditions... they why not go with `if-else` with introspection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call any Class (+) method the same way you call `alloc`. Like this:

```
[NSClassFromString(@"Car") importFromObject:anObject];
```